# Microsoft CRM plugin - Lookup is missing its name

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm working on a CRM 2011 plugin that should create new equipment entity with lookup to a vehicle entity:

```
var vehicle = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
var entity = new Entity("equipment");
// Fill other attributes

// Create lookup
var reference = vehicle.ToEntityReference();                 
entity.Attributes["new_vehiclelink"] = reference;
entity.Attributes["new_vehiclelinkname"] = name;

service.Create(equipment);
```

Equipment is created correctly unfortunately the lookup is missing its name.

[image]

When I click on the lookup it works. Please can you advice me how to fill its name?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your `vehicle` record has no value in its Primary Attribute (i.e. name). It is the Primary Attribute that gets displayed in the Lookup control.

I'm also unsure what this line is trying to do:

```
entity.Attributes["new_vehiclelinkname"] = name;
```

You don't need to set the name of the lookup value separately, so unless you have an additional attribute called `new_vehiclelinkname` then this is not necessary.